# How do I resolve Expo Go Andriod app crashing issue?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

The Expo Go Andriod app version `2.28.4` always crash on start. Like, when I start any app built with Expo, the Expo Go crashes. The expo app that I am building has not come up for 3 days now while it works well on simulator. The one I published on Expo also crashes. I read that the new update on Expo Go app came with a bug and I don't know when this would be fixed.
I honestly need to test my app features with two devices. I was using both the stimulator and the physical device to test these features. However since this crash started 3 days ago, I can't do anything anymore.
I have tried to download older versions and install on my Android phone but they are not installing. I am using Huawei p30.
Any installation of older version of Expo Go app gets 'App not installed' error. Only the latest version gets installed.
I am actually stranded. Any workaround?

Comment: What is the crash? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: No error, just closes instantly. For the app that I am currently building, I simply see Android Build complete. The Expo App crashes instantly after that. For the app I already published on Expo via expo publish, it simply closes without starting.

Comment: Since the application is crashing, there has to be an error and a stacktrace for it.

Comment: It is purely Expo Go app issue. I can see that Expo Go has been updated to version 2.28.5 and it is no longer crashing. It is actually a global issue after the last update. I was simply looking for a way around to manage before they fix the bug. Thanksfully, they fixed the bug in few days. I am still curious why I couldn't install older versions.

Answer (score 0):

The lastest update of Expo Go app from version `2.28.4` to version `2.28.5` fixed the crash issue.